# Background Shaders Compilation for Material Preview

Tags: shaders

When I switch from Solid to Material Preview, my view can lock up for many seconds while the Shaders Compile.  Is there some way to have blender load these in the background, when I first load a file that is in Solid shading mode, so as to get better response time on this?

[image]